# Is there a canonical name for 2 dimensional list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With Numpy

```
np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

this is a 2d array

without Numpy

```
list_2d = [[0, 1, 2],
[3, 4, 5],
[6, 7, 8]]
list_2d

[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

lots of people call this "2 dimensional list", "2-d list".

It seems that there is no occurrence of "2 dimensional list" in [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/)

So, is there a canonical name for this kind of list (list of lists) Python?

Comment: I imagine it would be called a list of lists

Comment: or a nested list

Comment: or a sequence of sequences

Comment: Why would you expect the python docs to explicitely mention something like this, and where should be "the end of it"? At a 99-dimensional-list? You can nest lists however deep you want.

Comment: @MikeScotty There would be a k-dimensional list, if there is a need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no canonical name for these objects.

Answer (score 1):

while there isn't a canonical name for this, most people would understand what you mean by "list of lists"

if you like the recent `typing` additions, you could spell this as:

```
from typing import List

list_2d: List[List[float]] = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
]
```

which would allow `mypy` to complain if you did something like:

```
list_2d[0][1] = 'foo'
```

saying:

```
error: No overload variant of "__setitem__" of "list" matches argument types "int", "str"
```